# Splitting and storing a unsigned char Buffer into a struct

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

For university I have to create a simple `TCP/IP` stack for a microcontroller.

I have an unsigned `char` `Buffer` of the packets that includes the Headers + the data (if present).

I created a `struct` for the packets that contains a struct for the ethernet header, a struct for the `IPv4 Header`, a struct for the `ARP` header and a `2024` `Byte` buffer for the actual data.

I would like to assign byte `0` dow to `21` to the Ethernet struct.
And `22` down to `53` to the `IPv4` Header.

My question now is how do you use `memcpy` to copy specific intervals from the buffer?

For example if I want to copy `buf[21 down to 53]` to `newbuf[32]`.

EDIT:
So to clarify the question and what I am Actually trying to accomplish:

I send this packet from the PC via Ethernet Cable to a microcontroller.
[image: Packet]
On the microcontroller I want to create a struct that contains all the information that you can see in the picture.

My approach so far is:

```
   struct ethernetHeader{
        unsigned char receiverMac[6];
        unsigned char senderMac [6];
        unsigned char type [2];
    };

    //Not sure how to convert unsigned char to Bit or atleast integer
    struct IPv4Header{
        //4 Bit  Version
        //4 Bit IHL
        //8 Bit Type of Service
        //16 Bit Packet length
        //16 Bit Identification
        // 3 Bit Flags
        //13 Bit Fragment offset
        //8 Bit TTL
        //8 Bit protocol
        //16 Bit Header Checksum
        //32 Bit Source IP
        //32 Bit Destination IP
        //32 Bit Options -> NULL will be discarded 

    };

    struct arpHeader{
        //to be defined 
    };

    struct frame{
        struct ethernetHeader ethHdr;
        struct IPv4Header ip4Hdr;
        struct arpHeader arpHdr;
        unsigned char buffer[2024];

    };
while(1) {

        //postpones execution if no event is available
        event_mask = Event_pend(my_network_events,NON_EVENT_MASK,(EMAC_RX_EVENT | EMAC_TX_EVENT | EMAC_RX_NO_BUFFER),BIOS_WAIT_FOREVER);


        /*no receiver buffer was available
         * */
        if(event_mask & EMAC_RX_NO_BUFFER) {
            FreeEmacRxBuf();
            EMACRxDMAPollDemand(EMAC0_BASE);
        }


         //
         // Check for an RX Packet and read it.
         //
         if(event_mask & EMAC_RX_EVENT)
         {
             // Get the packet and set uip_len for uIP stack usage.
             //

             eth_rx_ptr =  PacketReceive((int32_t *)(&eth_len));
             if(eth_len > ETH_BUFSIZE)
                 eth_len = ETH_BUFSIZE;//truncate received packet length if necessary

             /* copy to private buffer and free */
             memcpy(eth_buf,eth_rx_ptr,eth_len);
             FreeEmacRxBuf();
             eth_rx_ptr = NULL;
             struct ethernetHeader header;

             memcpy(header.receiverMac, &eth_buf[0], 6);
             memcpy(header.senderMac, &eth_buf[6], 6);
             memcpy(header.type, &eth_buf[12],2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question now is how do you use memcopy to copy specific intervals from the buffer?
>
> For example if I want to copy `buf[21 downto 53]` to `newbuf[32]`

So you will need to use pointer arithmetic in the source, (you have C++ an C tags you should remove one of those).

[**Something like**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/DutifulPartialMicroprogramming) (C++)

```
memcpy(newbuf, &buf[21], 32); // from buf[21] with the size of 32 bytes
```

Note that index `21` to `53` are actually `33` bytes.